# How to call Javascript Function in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular aplication and some JS code. I have seen that for previous angular versions, we have to put the JS into assets directory, in my case called Modulo_Tablas.js. Then, edite the angular.json to add this:

```
 "scripts": [
             "src/assets/Modulo_Tablas.js"
           ]
```

Then, add the declaration into the component.ts where I want to call the function like this:

```
declare function say_hi(): any;
```

So then, I should be able to do:

```
 sayhi(): void{
   say_hi();
 }
```

In my case, I decided to create a function called sayhi so when I click a button into my aplication, this function will be called. Then, the say_hi function will just do this:

```
function say_hi(){
  alert("how are you");
}
```

However, this is not working. What am I missing? Is now different for angular 11?

Comment: Make sure that your function is globally assigned to window object. Then you can acess it from your Angular app.

Comment: I think that should be `declare var say_hi:()=>void`. NOTE: Be careful, if you're using angular-cli, after change the angular.json you need "re-start" the `ng serve`